What does 「生活がかかる」 mean?
The character is scolding his university student employee for criticizing his work ethic and says this:
生活かかってない学生にはわからないかもしれないが本来ならその売上で悠長なこと言ってられないんだからな
My reading is that he's saying it "because you don' have to worry about your livehood you may not know, but with those sales, you can't such easygoing things"
What is the exact meaning of 生活かかってない?

This (～に)かかる means "to depend on ～" or "to be at stake". See the 14th definition here. かかる is this sense is commonly written in hiragana, but the kanji is 懸かる.

この作戦に全員の命がかかっている。
Everyone's lives depend on this operation.
彼の信頼が懸かっている。
His credibility is at stake.
(この仕事に)生活(が)かかってない学生
a student whose livelihood doesn't depend (on this work)

